# Como exibir lista do servlet em jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Boa noite. Pessoal, estou com uma dúvida a qual depois de N tentativas não se esclarece, então resolvi pedir ajuda aos mestres.
Basicamente, eu tenho o seguinte servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Chamando doGet");

    PrintWriter resposta = resp.getWriter();
    resposta.println("<html><body>");
    resposta.println("<strong>TESTANDO FORTE</strong>");

    resposta.println("<ul>");
    for (Artista u : new ArtistaDAO().getArtistas()) {
        resposta.println("<li>" + u.getNome() + "</li>");
    }
    resposta.println("</ul>");


    resposta.println("</body></html>");

    RequestDispatcher disp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/inicio.jsp");
    disp.forward(req, resp);
}
```

Esse servlet, (que tem a urlPatterns = "/buscar_artista") Quando acessado por /buscar_artista me retorna uma lista simples em html dos artistas cadastrados.
Porém, eu gostaria de obter essa lista na minha página JSP (Dashboard), assim que o usuário logar.
Sei que é possível usar com a taglib:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    ...
    ...
    ...
<c:forEach var="item" items="${artistas}">
<ul>
<li>Nome: ${item.getNome}</li> 
</ul>
</c:forEach>
```

Porém, para esta taglib funcionar eu devo ter um outro servlet que retorna outra lista?

Estou tentando passar com o seguinte servlet (Mas não esta funcionando):

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    synchronized(this){
        ArrayList<Artista> artistas = new ArtistaDAO().getArtistas();

        req.setAttribute("artistas", artistas);

        RequestDispatcher disp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/inicio.jsp");
    }
}
```

Resumindo bem a minha dúvida é: Como pegar todos os meus artistas do ArrayList e mostrar na dashboard assim que um usuário efetuar o login?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, ao fazer a requisição é possível verificar a ação pela qual foi feita através de envio do formulário. No exemplo abaixo, fiz a opção de envio do caminhos diferentes, caso for o redirecionamento para o mesmo local, pode retirar a opção de "acao", e apenas retornar lista. Segue o código abaixo:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
   String acao= req.getParameter("acao");
    if (acao!=null){
        switch (acao) {           
        case "listaArtista":
            String caminho = "/busca_artista.jsp";
            List<Artista> lista = artistaDAO.getArtistas();
            envioLista(req, resp, lista, caminho);
            break;           
        case "listaLogin":
            String caminho = "/login.jsp";
            List<Artista> lista = artistaDAO.getArtistas();
            envioLista(req, resp, lista, caminho);
            break;
        }
    }else{
        //Pode passar a lista aqui novamente ou alguma mensagem de validação
    }
}
```

Nessa função faz o envio da lista e o caminho que são passados como parâmetro:

```
private void envioLista(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, List lista, String caminho)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(caminho);
    req.setAttribute("lista", lista);
    dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
}
```

Exemplo no formulário

```
 <div class="row">
      <form action="/busca_artista" method="post" id="buscaArtista" role="form">       
        <input type="text" id="acao" name="acao" value="listaArtista"> <!-- esse campo tem que ser hidden na hora do envio-->
        <!-- o restante do código ... -->
      </form>
</div>
```